# Incompatible types when returning a generic

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement HashMap in Java, but I get this error when trying to return the value. This is the `Entry` class:

```
public class Entry<K,V> {
private K key;
private V value;
public Entry next;
public Entry(K key, V value)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public K getKey() {
    return key;
}

public V getValue() {

    return value;
}

public void setValue(V value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

And this is what I want to return:

```
    private Entry[] buckets = new Entry[255];


    public V getValue(K key){
    int hash = key.hashCode()%buckets.length-1;
    Entry currentEntry = buckets[hash];
    while (currentEntry!=null)
    {
        if (currentEntry.getKey().equals(key)){
            return currentEntry.getValue(); //error here
        }
    currentEntry = currentEntry.next;
    }

    return null;
    }
```

The error I get is `Error:(47, 45) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to V`

Comment: I suspect that `Entry currentEntry` should be `Entry<K, V> currentEntry`; also with `buckets`.

Comment: ... and as is, this code should issue an "unchecked" warning.

Comment: And also `int hash = key.hashCode()%buckets.length-1` is problematic as it can return a value of `-1`, which would throw an exception in the following statement.

Comment: @JimGarrison Also a negative hash code will still be negative after `%` with a positive integer. `Maths.abs` is "surprising" for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Usual solution is to make the table length **a power of two** and use `key.hashCode() & (buckets.length-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry` has type parameters but you also have an array of `Entry`. The two don't go together. You have a number of options including:

- Remove the type parameters from `Entry` and use unsafe casts.
- Instead of using array, punt to a `List` of some description.
- Do away with the `Entry` object and use a probing algorithm with `Object[]` array and unsafe casts.
- Use an unsafe cast to initialise `buckets`.
- Replace the entire algorithm with a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I had modified your getValue method signature on line 1 and below works fine for me.
Also added generics on line 3 with Entry value initialization.

Although line 2 code , hash initialization i find poor but cannot comment much until and unless we see your **put(K key,V value)** method.

```
public <K> V getValue(K key){ // line 1
        int hash = key.hashCode()%buckets.length-1; // line 2
        Entry<K, V> currentEntry = buckets[hash]; //line 3
        while (currentEntry!=null)
        {
            if (currentEntry.getKey().equals(key)){
                return currentEntry.getValue(); 
            }
        currentEntry = currentEntry.next;
        }

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add generic to your declaration:

```
Entry<K,V> currentEntry = buckets[hash];
```

Comment: Generics don't work with arrays. `Cannot create generic array of Entry<K,V>`. Did you try compiling this?